# Decode JSON with Circe and Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js, circe

I try to create veeery simple scala.js app. I was following this tutorial https://www.scala-js.org/doc/tutorial/scalajs-vite.html
and I want to decode a json.

Circe
https://circe.github.io/circe/
says
`circe also provides a parser subproject that provides parsing support for Scala.js, with JVM parsing provided by io.circe.jawn and JavaScript parsing from scalajs.js.JSON.`

So according to
https://circe.github.io/circe/parsing.html I have

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.parser._
val myValue = parse(event.data.toString)
```

and with the following dependencies

```
"io.circe" %% "circe-core" % "0.14.5",
"io.circe" %% "circe-parser" % "0.14.5",
```

That gives the following errors

```
[error] Referring to non-existent class io.circe.parser.package$
[error] Cannot access module for non-module io.circe.parser.package$
[error] Referring to non-existent method 
io.circe.parser.package$.parse(java.lang.String)scala.util.Either
```

Exactly the same type of error as for JVM only libraries :|

Comment: I think Scala.js dependencies need to be imported with `%%%` (triple ampersend), e.g. `"io.circe" %%% "circe-core" % "0.14.5"`

Comment: Yes the three %%% should do the trick here. Note that you can also decode a JSON directly with the browser's JS engine (if your class is "js enough" which means some restrictions), for instance through native-converter: https://august.nagro.us/scalajs-native-converter.html

Comment: Thank you @stefanobaghino, you should post a big answer.

Comment: Cool, I didn't have time to check it properly but glad it was correct. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment I wrote and that turned out to be correct, Scala.js modules need to be declared with the `%%%` operator in your sbt build definition, so your two dependencies would need to be declared as follows:

```
"io.circe" %%% "circe-core" % "0.14.5",
"io.circe" %%% "circe-parser" % "0.14.5",
```

You can read more about it [here on the documentation of Scala.js.](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/dependencies.html)